# Calculate the average of adjacent elements to fill nan values in a numpy array in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Here, need fill nan values using the Average of adjacent elements.

| index | data |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | a |
| 1 | (a+b)/2)(nan is replaced) |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |
| 4 | c+(d-c)/3(nan is replaced) |
| 5 | c+2*(d-c)/3(nan is replaced) |
| 6 | d |

and so on.
i.e.

| index | Input Data | Expected output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | nan | nan |
| 1 | nan | nan |
| 2 | nan | nan |
| 3 | nan | nan |
| 4 | 42980 | 42980 |
| 5 | 41850 | 41850 |
| 6 | nan | 43313.5 |
| 7 | 44777 | 44777 |
| 8 | 43277.8 | 43277.8 |
| 9 | 37999.2 | 37999.2 |
| 10 | 40441.1 | 40441.1 |
| 11 | 36934.6 | 36934.6 |
| 12 | nan | 39739.73333 |
| 13 | nan | 42544.86667 |
| 14 | 45350 | 45350 |
| 15 | 41831 | 41831 |
| 16 | 47688.6 | 47688.6 |
| 17 | 45185 | 45185 |
| 18 | nan | 45750.75 |
| 19 | nan | 46316.5 |
| 20 | nan | 46882.25 |
| 21 | 47448 | 47448 |
| 22 | 45094 | 45094 |
| 23 | 39944.9 | 39944.9 |
| 24 | nan | 40549.12 |
| 25 | nan | 41153.34 |
| 26 | nan | 41757.56 |
| 27 | nan | 42361.78 |
| 28 | 42966 | 42966 |
| 29 | 39133 | 39133 |
| 30 | nan | nan |

Comment: I think you are you looking for linear interpolation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html

Comment: OK! thank you. I understand what I should do.

Comment: No problems, happy to help :)